# simple forloop with instance tag

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-cms

I want to pass data from models to template using CMS_plugins.py
I've made an app and standalone works. When i open link manualy
`localhost:port/en/post_list.html` all values are shown and works. 
If i go on admin page and add plugin, values in mysql are stored but not presended in my template.html . I want to pass values in template.html

EDIT:

I manage to pass values to template. I edited cms_plugins.py
How can i hook data with "for" ?.
In code blow, nothing isnt shown in my template.html

```
<p>{{instance.firstline}}</p>  ->>>this works


    { %block content %}
        {{ instance.post.offer_option}}
        <p>{{post.firstline}}</p>
        <p>{{post.secline}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock}
```

if i change to :

```
{% for post in posts %}
   <p>{{post.firstline}}</p>
        <p>{{post.secline}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock}
```

In upper case if i run manualy url: `localhost:port/en/pricing` , I can see the result i want to be rendered in template.In template nothing isnt shown neither.

cms_plugins.py

```
 class pricing(CMSPluginBase):
        model = Post
        name = _("pricing")
        render_template = "post_list.html"
        cache = False

          def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance': instance})
        return context



    plugin_pool.register_plugin(pricing)
```